# Is Chef/Ruby flattening my SortedSet attribute into a String?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I tried to create a normal level attribute which is a SortedSet. This initially appears to work, but when a subsequent recipe tries to access it, it looks like it's become a String.

First recipe

```
require "pp"

node.normal['test'] = SortedSet.new([1,2,3])
pp node['test'] 
#      displays #<SortedSet: {1, 2, 3}>
```

Second recipe

```
require "pp"

pp node['test']
#      displays "#<SortedSet:0x0000000355e260>"
mySet = node['test'] 
mySet.add(1) 
#      undefined method `add' for "#<SortedSet:0x0000000355e260>":String
```

What's happened? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Nodes attributes being a crated hash named `mash`, which aim at storing string, array and hash values, I assume there's a call to `to_s` on every other class,  which transform your SortedSet object to a String representation (remark the second pp call gives a SortedSet:0x... and not the object itself). I'm digging the code before writing an answer with links on the why. (Side note: this sounds a XY problem, if you wish sorted values you probably can achieve it in recipe)

Comment: Cheers - the SortedSet bit was just something I was trying out and I don't actually need to use now (for the reasons you menition). I was just curious what was going on, a) because I don't like it when I don't understand some behaviour and b) presumably it may happen again when I do need to use some other class

Comment: For your b), avoid esoteric uses of attributes, usually there's should not be complex types in attributes. the code involved is above my ruby level to explain why it convert to string, so if you dare digging on it: [it's here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/node/attribute_collections.rb)